# User defined threshold for random module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make it so that the user can define the threshold for generating a random number (i.e. Min and Max values) I am using random module. Here is what I have so far but the code wont run.

```
print('Random Number Generator')
min = input('Enter your minimum value:')
max = input('Enter your maximum value: ')

num = (random.randint({0},{1})).format (min, max)

print('Your random number is: {0}').format(num)
```

I can think of another way of doing it (generating and rejecting numbers that don't fall within the threshold but it seems wasteful)

Comment: Please show the error you get when you try to run your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
import random

minv = int(input('Enter your minimum value: '))
maxv = int(input('Enter your maximum value: '))

num = random.randint(minv, maxv)
```